# ¿Como soluciono un error por pasarle un objeto a un método en un archivo aparte? C#

Tags: c#, array, lista, class, imprimir

Les consulto, tengo estos 2 archivos que interactuan realizando el alta de un producto a través de un menu, ademas de tener una clase en otro donde se debería imprimir el contenido de los objetos. Pero al pasarle la lista de objetos me sale un error de referencia.  ¿Que estoy omitiendo en el codigo?

Primero archivo con el menu.

```
namespace TP_Integrador
{

    public class MenuProductos
    {
        public MenuProductos()
        {

        }

        public static void mascara()
        {
            int opcion = 1;

            List<Productos> arrAlta = new List<Productos>();

            while(opcion!=5)
            {


                Console.Write( "----------------------MODULO PRODUCTOS----------------------"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n");
                Console.WriteLine("¿Que desea hacer?"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n");
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Dar de Alta Productos");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Imprimir");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - ");
                Console.WriteLine("4 - ");
                Console.WriteLine("5 - ");

                Console.Write("Opcion: ");
                opcion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch(opcion)
                {
                    case 1:
                        arrAlta = AltaDeProducto.alta();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ImprimirProducto.Imprimir(arrAlta);
                        //Promociones.descuento(arrAlta);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Compras");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        break;

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Segundo archivo con el Alta del producto:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TP_Integrador
{

 public class AltaDeProducto
 {

    List<Productos> AProducto = new List<Productos>();

    public List<Productos> alta()
    {
        string respuesta = "si";

        do
        {       
            //Declaro los objetos y comienzo con la carga de datos
            var producto = new Productos();

            Console.WriteLine("Usted eligio: Productos y Promociones"+"\n");
            Console.Write("Ingrese Tipo: ");
            producto.tipo = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Ingrese Marca: ");
            producto.marca = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Ingrese Talle: ");
            producto.talle = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Ingrese Precio: ");
            producto.precio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //Agrego el objeto cargado a la lista...
            AProducto.Add(producto);

            Console.Write("Cargado!"+"\n");
            Console.Write("Desea ingresar otro? ");
            respuesta=Console.ReadLine(); 
        }while(respuesta=="si");

        return AProducto;
    }

 }

}
```

Tercer archivo que posee un método al que se le pasa por parámetro el objeto cargado y lo muestra:

```
namespace TP_Integrador
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of ImprimirProducto.
    /// </summary>
    public class ImprimirProducto
    {

        public static void Imprimir(List<Productos> AProducto)
        {                       
            foreach(Productos item in AProducto)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tipo: " + item.tipo);
                    Console.WriteLine("Marca: " + item.marca);
                    Console.WriteLine("Talle: " + item.talle);
                    Console.WriteLine("Precio: " + item.precio);
                }
        }


    }
}
```

**ERROR:** 
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TP_Integrador.AltaDeProducto.alta()' (CS0120) - C:\Users\Mloprete\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\TP Integrador\TP Integrador\MenuProductos.cs:48,17

Razonamiento: El error puede estar en como defino los métodos? Sea en estado static? o seguro debo tener alguna referencia errónea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mariano, en tu primer código el switch - case debería ser:

```
switch(opcion)
{
     case 1:
         //Debes instanciar tu clase
         var prod = new AltaDeProducto();
         arrAlta = prod.alta();
     break;
     case 2:
         ImprimirProducto.Imprimir(arrAlta);
         //Promociones.descuento(arrAlta);
     break;
     case 3:
         Console.WriteLine("Compras");
     break;
     case 4:
         Console.WriteLine("");
     break;
     default:
         Console.WriteLine("");
     break;
}
```

Comment: Ah!! Entonces lo que recibe la variable arrAlta es a lista entera con los objetos cargados. Funciona perfecto!